# skip yii2 unique validation on update action if new value equals to prev value

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

Because of unique validator get error on update action ('this username is already taken') i wanna validate username on update action when new username value not equals to prev value, it's my rule:

```
        [['username'], 'unique', 'on'=>'update', 'when' => function($model){
                return static::getOldUsername($model->id) !== $model->username;
            }
        ],
```

and it's my function to get prev username value:

```
public static function getOldUsername($id)
{
    return static::findIdentity($id)->username;
}
```

but it doesn't work, i think $model->getId() return nothing because of with static id (e.g: 23) its work.

```
        [['username'], 'unique', 'on'=>'update', 'when' => function($model){
                return static::getOldUsername(23) !== $model->username;
            }
        ],
```

how can i get model id? or if you have other ways to skip yii2 unique validation on update action if new value equals to prev value, please explain it.

Comment: i should say that my code is right and it works good now, error comes from a `,`. Oops!! I hope this question be useful for other viewers, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use `$user->isAttributeChanged('username');`

Example (I'm not testing this code):

```
[['username'], 'unique', 'on'=>'update', 'when' => function($model){
    return $model->isAttributeChanged('username')
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'login', 'unique', 
    'targetAttribute' => ['login'], 
    'filter' => ['!=', 'id', Yii::$app->request->get('id')], 
    'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 
    'message' => 'This login has already been taken.',
],
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.